# Preventing access same record by multiple user in MS SQL 2005 . 

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

if one user accessing the record 1 out of 10 records in a table. if at the same time, 2nd user trying to access that same record of 1st user, he should not be displayed that record but instead he should be displayed 2nd record and because this first user will be holding the record for some time to process and update till then this records should not be shown to any other user even select query is fired from second user application. is it possible using Row Lock? please provide me the example how to implement rowlock and holdlock and release the hold lock used Row level lock. apart from this if you have any other suggestion please share it

I am using SqlServer2005 with Asp.Net

Babu.M

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if row lock would stop it being selected but could you not use a audit table? For example when user one gets access to the record store the ID for that record in an audit table and then when user two trys to use a record the application should check to see if the primary key for the record is in the audit table, if it is the second user does not gain access if not the second user gains access. Once a user has finished with the record you can either delete the record in th audit table or you could keep the record but set a flag to say it is no longer in use as this way you could see who has changed what record and at what time if you add a date time stamp.

Again when using select command just make it so that if the primary key is present in the audit table you don't select it.

Hope this helps